# Text-Shadow: IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

Alright, so I'm trying to implement `text-shadow` across various browsers. I have IE6, IE7, FF, Chrome, and Opera all working... but IE8 wont' show any shadows unless it is in 'Compatibility View'.

I've looked at a number of 'solutions' via search / Google, but the shadow is still only appearing in 'Compatibility View'.

Any ideas on how to get it to show up without having to change modes?

***Note:** Using HTML5 Boilerplate and Modernizr.*

edit: Added that I'm using Modernizr, and I clicked the wrong button in my tester. This isn't working in IE9 either, but I don't think it is related.

**CSS:**

```
#links li a {
font-size: 24px;
text-shadow: 0 3px 3px #102530, 0 3px 3px #102530;
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=90, Color='#102530')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=90, Color='#102530');
filter:DropShadow(Color=#102530, OffX=0, OffY=3);
zoom: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="links">
    <li><a href="#"/>Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you can only use `filter` once, and if you want more than one effect, use a comma to separate. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: I can't believe I'm booting up [Windows XP Mode](https://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) for this...

Comment: I'm only using one filter for IE. I use the comma separated `text-shadow` first, but then there are two fall-backs, one for IE8, and one for IE5.5-7.0, but the IE8 fallback doesn't seem to work without compatibility mode. 

Edit: Thanks BoltClock, haha

Comment: I made this work, but the drop shadow looks so **awful** in IE8 that I'm not going to post it as an answer. Forget about the IE drop shadow, it looks disgusting: http://i.imgur.com/R1rBl.png

Comment: I guess this is why `text-shadow` didn't make it into IE9 either.

Comment: Something I just thought of - I could just use a different background image for my LI containers that had a dimmed middle to help the text pop up more. It's a bit disappointing on Microsoft's part though... as usual.

Comment: Multiple filter effects don’t need commas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A website must not necessarily look the same in every browser. Plus MS filters are crap. 
I would recommend to use [Modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/) an apply a different solution for IE8.

It will save you from headaches :)

Comment: I am using Modernizr, but would rather not add non-semantic mark-up if I can avoid it.

Comment: If anything is non semantic it is MS filters. Modernizer classes are as valid as you can get.

Comment: Validity doesn't really matter too much to me. CSS should include all styling and HTML should include all the information. If I need to include an extra filter that isn't a standard, that is fine by me. But adding an extra span tag and duplicating the text seems a bit silly. I should also add that the shadow is a bit important as without it, there is very little contrast between the text and the background.

Comment: Read the documentation for Modernizer, you don't need to add anything except write a few words in your CSS that will save you from lots of trouble.

Comment: I was talking about doing a manual text-shadow to compensate for browsers that don't support `text-shadow`. I'll probably just use `.no-textshadow` and toss it a different background image.

Comment: Yup :) That is exactly what i had in mind what I was suggesting to apply a different solution for IE8. Glad you solved it.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of modernizr in action.

Answer (score 11):

I tried [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) (also with [heygrady's polyfill](https://github.com/heygrady/textshadow)). I tried [cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/). I tried [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/). But none of them displayed me a text-shadow in Internet Explorer 8 (CSS3PIE doesn't feature `text-shadow`). I also tried the [double-markup method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172682/using-internet-explorer-filters-and-cleartype). But that really can't be it.

And then I found [Whykiki's blog post](http://www.thewhykiki.de/css-text-schatten-bzw-schatten-im-internet-explorer/) and simply added `filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=2, offy=2);` in combination with `display: block;`. And that's it. Some of you might try `zoom: 1;` instead of `display: block;` to activate it. `filter: glow(color=#000000,strength=2);` works, too. As you will see, the MS dropshadow doesn't come with blur. I can live with that.

```
h1 {
  color: #fce934;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
  -moz-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
  -webkit-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
  filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=2, offy=2);
  display: block; /* that's the important part */
}
```

Comment: This should be the chosen anwer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...worked great for my IE8 issue.