# IE 8 Adding Text-shadow

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, dijit.form

I'm running into a strange issue -- in one of my form elements, it looks like text-shadow is being added only for IE 8.

Even when I add a:

```
text-shadow: 0px transparent;
```

It still appears. Has anyone seen something like this before?

I am using dojo / dijit, and when I specifically target the element even with something like

```
color: red;
```

It does not have any effect in IE 8, though it does in other modern browsers.
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the HTML for this form element? It looks like a disabled textarea. Note that IE8 doesn't support text-shadow, so you won't be able to use that property to change it. (Also, to remove a text-shadow, you use `text-shadow: none`.)

Comment: I am using dijit.form.NumberSpinner (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/NumberSpinner.html) to generate the HTML; thanks for the reference as well. I'm not sure if it's text-shadow or not -- what else could it look like?

Comment: Ah, so it's a custom spinner control. Well, it looks like embossed text (with a background that isn't the usual white), which is why I suspect it's a disabled control. That is applied by the browser based on system rendering of controls and is not something usually targetable with CSS.

Comment: Ah yeah it is disabled. That's crazy it's un-targetable. Thanks for the info though :)

Comment: That's that, then. No problem, I posted an answer. I've gotta get going now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not support the `text-shadow` property prior to version 10, so setting it won't have any effect there.

Since your form control is disabled, that's IE8 rendering it according to how the OS draws disabled controls in general. There isn't much you can do to change this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using either a ms filter or poly for this....

Are you using Modernizr? If not I recommend using it so you can call ie8 css to disable or change the css method on this text shadow.

HEre is a similar same issue/answer:

[Text-Shadow: IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759334/text-shadow-ie8)

Comment: This is not an answer; and should added in comment section.

Comment: Why not? What do you expect on all answers? code?....you can solve this easily with Modernizr.....

Comment: The issue isn't that I want to negate whatever effect is creating this -- unfortunately I am inheriting a few different stylesheets but am unsure what to look for. You think this is 'filter' attribute?

Comment: possibly yes... ms filter...go inspect that input element and see what your css code shows